# Write a tactic for prooving if two lists are permutations

Tags: coq

I am a beginner and I would like to write a tactic for proving if two lists are permutations.

For example, I would like to check the tactic with :

```
Goal (Permutation (1::3::4::2::nil) (2::4::1::3::nil))
```

I have written a function to sort a list and to check if 2 lists are equals but I have some troubles to write a tactic.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Please add the code of your function so people can help you

Comment: You don't need to see the code, i'd just like to know how write a tactic for prooving if two lists are permutations. 

I have just written 2 functions :
- listS list returns the sorted list l
- EqualL list1 list2 returns true if list1 and list2 are equals else false

Comment: For your particular example, you don't need a tactic. Just prove `forall l1 l2, to_prop (EqualL (listS l1) (listS l2)) -> Permutation l1 l2`, apply that to the goal, simplify, and apply `I`. `to_prop : bool -> Prop`. If your lists have variables, that's a whole different story.

Comment: Hey Rui Baptista, Thank you for your answer. I'm a beginner and i don't understand very well what you said.You suggest to do :
"Goal forall l1 l2, to_prop (EqualL (listS l1) (listS l2)) -> Permutation l1 l2" but actually Permutation is not defined. By the way, my function EqualL takes two natural lists and returns a Prop (True or False) so i think i don't need "to_prop".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh. By write a tactic I thought you meant write a decision procedure to automate your proofs. And I thought you were refering to the `Permutation` relation defined in `Coq.Sorting.Permutation`.

If you just want to prove that your lists are permutations of each other, you can do it like so:

```
Definition Permutation : list nat -> list nat -> Prop :=
  fun l1 l2 => EqualS (sortL l1) (sortL l2).

Goal Permutation (1 :: 3 :: 4 :: 2 :: nil) (2 :: 4 :: 1 :: 3 :: nil).
Proof. lazy. tauto. Qed.
```

The definition of `True` is

```
Inductive True : Prop :=
  | I : True.
```

If you want to prove something more general, like

```
forall n1 n2 n3 n4, Permutation (n1 :: n2 :: n3 :: n4 :: nil) (n4 :: n3 :: n2 :: n1 :: nil)
```

you'll have to prove some facts about your functions first, like, for example,

```
forall n1 n2 l1, sortL (n1 :: n2 :: l1) = sortL (n2 :: n1 :: l1)
forall n1 l1 l2, EqualS (n1 :: l1) (n1 :: l2) <-> EqualS l1 l2
```

and you'll have to rewrite with those.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exacty what i needed ! ;)